# KendoUI - Draw DOM and Grid then save together into PDF

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How to draw DOM and Grid into one PDF with KendoUI ?

For example: I have summary header for my grids, it's seperated DOM element (.report-header) and Kendo.Grid (.report-table). I want draw them into one PDF file. For now i have this :

```
<div id="report">
  <div class="report-header"></div>
  <div class="report-table"></div>
</div>

kendo.drawing.drawDOM("#report", {
            allPages: true,
            avoidLinks: true,
            paperSize: "A4",
            margin: { top: "1cm", left: "1cm", right: "1cm", bottom: "1cm" },
            landscape: true,
            repeatHeaders: true,
            template: $("#page-template").html(),
            scale: 0.5,
            title: 'Raport dzienny'
        }).then(function(group){
            kendo.drawing.pdf.saveAs(group, 'file.pdf');
        });
```

And it's working but table is not drawn all. How to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

I can't see the `$("#page-template").html()`. It needs to be created.

Something like this:

```
<script type="x/kendo-template" id="page-template">
    <div class="page-template">
        <div class="header">
            <div style="float: right">Page #: pageNum # of #: totalPages #</div>
            Multi-page grid with automatic page breaking
        </div>
        <div class="watermark">KENDO UI</div>
        <div class="footer">Page #: pageNum # of #: totalPages #</div>
    </div>
</script>
```